# channel 34: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

Tags: 14.04, ssh, proxy, tunnel, socks5

I'm using a ssh-tunnel to a server (Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 x86_64) with a socks5 proxy. To build up the connection I'm using the following command:

```
ssh -D 62378 user@server.de
```

The socks5 proxy works fine: over http://www.whatismyip.com/ I get the IP from the server I'm connected to.

But sometimes I get the following information on the servers command line:

```
channel 34: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 63: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 67: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
```

When the server throws this messages the connection still works fine. So what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I've found out whats going on here:

The socks5 proxy has a connection limit and when there are too many requests, the proxy throws these messages. This message also appears when the proxy server does not respond at all.